# Tibco ActiveMatrix ESB Iso-8583 Connector

Tags: esb, iso8583

Some Enterprise Service Bus solutions like Mule ESB or WSO2 ESB use connectors to support ISO8583 standard messages - there are connectors that have been developed and are maintained for the above two. Does anyone know of a connector that can work with Tibco ActiveMatrix ESB? What does it take to develop a connect for a given ESB to support ISO 8583 messages?

Answer (score 1):

I understand Tibco uses jPOS

See http://devzone.tibco.com/sites/streambase/10.0.0/dtmexamples/examples/jposchannel/example.html

and you can too.

Answer (score 1):

For TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks 6.x (TIBCO's integration product line) you can use the Plugin Development Kit ([PDK](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-development-kit-6-1-1)) to develop custom connectors. These connectors are based on Java and you can you bring your own Jar files that you likely already have for the ISO messages.

An alternative would be to create a Java Process Starter which does pretty much the same, but won't require you to go through the extra steps of building a full plugin (with custom installers). Both methods have their merits, based on what your use case is. There is a sample project included with BusinessWorks that covers the [Java Process Starter](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.5.0/doc/html/GUID-4C76CA61-5557-48B7-B7E2-3B1418DA5366.html).